# What does this Chinese seal translate to?

Tags: translation, meaning, seal

[image: Chinese Seal]

I have just recently bought this from a antique shop nearby and would like to know what it translates too

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It read: [賽特](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E8%B5%9B%E7%89%B9) (transliteration of Seth)

> 賽特（Set，也作 Seth，Setekh等），又名西德，在埃及神話中最初是力量之神，戰神，風暴之神，沙漠之神以及外陸之神。

> Set (Set, also known as Seth, Setekh, etc.), also known as Xī Dé, was originally the god of power, the god of war, the god of storms, the god of the desert, and the god of the outer land in Egyptian mythology.

[image]

It is not an ancient Chinese seal, it is a 浮雕 (relief)

A seal would have mirrored image of the words

[image]

Comment: If it is an ancient Chinese seal, then its meaning cannot be that of a Western mythological figure.

Comment: It is not an ancient Chinese seal, it is a 浮雕 (relief)

Comment: but in the picture provided by the author, it is obviously a Chinese seal as in the page: https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=chinese%20seal&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=chineseal&sc=10-9&cvid=11EA5E63690541DFA1A4EC67B610547E&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&first=1&tsc=ImageHoverTitle

Comment: If it is a seal, the words would be mirrored

Comment: I think the OP mirrored it for us.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "赛" and "特"。 If it is an old seal, the direction should from right to left (so should be 特赛)。 "特赛" seems like not a Chinese word  so it has no meaning.  Moreover, since the word is in the seal, the separate meanings of these two common characters are meaningless here. It may be a name of someone or a company / organization.